# Making Monic polynomial problem

Tags: number-theory

Problem) Determine whether $2^{-1/3}+2^{-2/3}$ is rational or irrational.

The problem is to be solved by using monic polynomial's property

Which is that 'IF the root of monic polynomial is rational, then the root is integer'

I think that by using contraposition, if we can find monic polynomial for given number,   then by 'the given number is not integer.', we can prove given number is irrational.

but i don't know how can i find the monic polynimial for give number...

Comment: Compare with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/minimal-polynomial-of-1-21-3-41-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $x=2^{-1/3}+2^{-2/3},$ then $x^3=\frac12+3\cdot\frac12\cdot x+\frac14$.

Comment: Coefficients of monic polynomial must be integer.

Comment: If this rational polynomial (Monic or otherwise) has no rational roots, your number cannot be rational.

Comment: How can we determine your 3-order equ has no rational roots?

Comment: Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: In interger coefficients monic polynomial, we can check whether the root is integer or not but rational.coefficient equ .. i dont know how to do

Comment: Did you check the link I posted? It's for rational polynomials (or integer polynomials which are not necessarily monic). It is more general than the one you seem familiar with.

Comment: Wowowow you right i thought that the same thing yours is more.general i found that q|4 in your equ ( changing to.integer coefficients ex).multiply 4 )

Comment: And also p|3 therefore everyting is solved  thank you